# Debug grails script command

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I want to debug a Grails 2.5.3 script - specifically from the `release` plugin, the command is `grails maven-deploy`, although I would hope it's no different than trying to debug a `generate-controller` command, or anything else that is built-in.

I can find the `scripts/MavenDeploy.groovy` script file, and the `MavenDeploy.groovy` source file. I've set breakpoints in both, and tried to debug the command (from IntelliJ), but with no luck.

I see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181006/how-to-debug-grails-command) which sounds the same, but the accepted answer is just about debugging the `run-app` command, which is different than what I'm trying to do.